# Search extension in teams gives "We didn't find any matches" message, when I close selected item

Tags: .net, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am creating a teams search extension using .net and there I am showing a list of items, when I click on an item it's redirecting to a customized card(adaptive card).

but when I close the selected card it's showing "We didn't find any matches" message without going back to the search list.

I am mentioning the codes below.

code for returning the list of items.

```
protected override async Task<MessagingExtensionResponse> OnTeamsMessagingExtensionQueryAsync(ITurnContext<IInvokeActivity> turnContext, MessagingExtensionQuery query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
       
        var text = query?.Parameters?[0]?.Value as string ?? string.Empty;    
        var attachments = new List<MessagingExtensionAttachment>();
        var userConfigSettings = await _userConfigProperty.GetAsync(turnContext, () => string.Empty);
        var userConfigSettingsConstituents = await _userConfigPropertyConstituents.GetAsync(turnContext, () => string.Empty);
        var state = query.State; // Check the state value          
        List<ConstituentSummary> constituentSummariesPreviewList = null;
        
        if (state != null)
        {
            userConfigSettings = state.ToString();
            await _userConfigProperty.SetAsync(turnContext, userConfigSettings, cancellationToken);
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userConfigSettings))
        {
            if (query.QueryOptions.Skip == 0)
            {
                InterfaceAppHelper interfaceAppHelper = new InterfaceAppHelper();
                constituentSummaries = await Task.Run(() => interfaceAppHelper.GetConstituentSummary(userConfigSettings, text));
                userConfigSettingsConstituents = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(constituentSummaries);
                await _userConfigPropertyConstituents.SetAsync(turnContext, userConfigSettingsConstituents, cancellationToken);
            }
            else
            {
                constituentSummaries = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ConstituentSummary>>(userConfigSettingsConstituents);
            }
           if(constituentSummaries!=null && constituentSummaries.Count>(query.QueryOptions.Count+query.QueryOptions.Skip))
            {                   
               constituentSummariesPreviewList = GetConstituentsPreviewList(constituentSummaries, query.QueryOptions.Skip, query.QueryOptions.Count);                   
            }
            else
            {
                var count = constituentSummaries?.Count - query.QueryOptions.Skip;
                constituentSummariesPreviewList = GetConstituentsPreviewList(constituentSummaries, query.QueryOptions.Skip, count);
            }              
            attachments = constituentSummariesPreviewList.Select(constitunetSummary =>
             {
                 var previewCard = new ThumbnailCard
                 {                         
                     Title = constitunetSummary.Name,
                     Text = constitunetSummary.LookupID,                         
                     Images = new List<CardImage>
                        {
                         new CardImage
                         {
                             Url=constitunetSummary.Url,
                         }
                         }, 
                     
                     Tap =new CardAction
                    {
                        Type="invoke",                           
                        Value= constitunetSummary,
                        //Text= text,                            
                     }
                 };                   
                 var attachment = new MessagingExtensionAttachment
                 {
                     ContentType = HeroCard.ContentType,
                     Content = new HeroCard
                     {
                         Title = constitunetSummary.Name,
                         Text = constitunetSummary.LookupID,                            
                     },                        
                     Preview =previewCard.ToAttachment()
                 };
                 return attachment;
             }).ToList();
            return new MessagingExtensionResponse
            {
                ComposeExtension = new MessagingExtensionResult
                {
                    Type = "result",
                    AttachmentLayout = "list",
                    Attachments = attachments
                }
            };
        }
        else
        {
            // The list of MessagingExtensionAttachments must we wrapped in a MessagingExtensionResult wrapped in a MessagingExtensionResponse.
            return new MessagingExtensionResponse
            {
                ComposeExtension = new MessagingExtensionResult
                {
                    Type = "auth",
                    SuggestedActions = new MessagingExtensionSuggestedAction
                    {
                        Actions = new List<CardAction>
                    {
                        new CardAction
                        {
                        Type = ActionTypes.OpenUrl,
                        Value = $"https://ba31fd2e23c3.ngrok.io/auth.html",
                        Title = "Please Login to the system",
                        },
                    }
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

code for show selected item -

```
protected override Task<MessagingExtensionResponse> OnTeamsMessagingExtensionSelectItemAsync(ITurnContext<IInvokeActivity> turnContext, JObject query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // The Preview card's Tap should have a Value property assigned, this will be returned to the bot in this event. 
        ConstituentSummary constituentSummary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ConstituentSummary>(query.ToString());
        var userConfigSettings = _userConfigProperty.GetAsync(turnContext, () => string.Empty).Result;
        InterfaceAppHelper interfaceAppHelper = new InterfaceAppHelper();
        constituentSummary = interfaceAppHelper.GetConstituentSummaryFromConstituentId(userConfigSettings, constituentSummary.Id);
        string constituencyName = string.Empty;
        if (constituentSummary.Constituencies != null && constituentSummary.Constituencies.Count > 0)
        {
            constituencyName = constituentSummary.Constituencies[0].Description;
        }
        var adaptiveCard = CreateAdaptiveCard(constituentSummary);
        var thumbnailCard = new ThumbnailCard
        {
            Title = constituentSummary.Name,
            Text = constituentSummary.LookupID,
            Images = new List<CardImage>
                        {
                         new CardImage
                         {
                             Url=constituentSummary.Url,
                         }
                         },
            Tap = new CardAction
            {
                Type = ActionTypes.MessageBack,
                Value = constituentSummary,                                             
            }
        };
        var attachment = new MessagingExtensionAttachment
        {
            ContentType = AdaptiveCard.ContentType,
            Content = adaptiveCard,
            Preview = thumbnailCard.ToAttachment()
        };
    
        return Task.FromResult(new MessagingExtensionResponse
        {
            ComposeExtension = new MessagingExtensionResult
            {
                Type = "result",
                AttachmentLayout = "list",
                Attachments = new List<MessagingExtensionAttachment> { attachment }
            }
        });
    }
```

Note that I am using same preview card in both methods.

this is an image of search list that I get
[image]

this is the card that I get when selecting an item

[image]

and this is what I get when I click the cross in red box(in the above image)
[image]

it's same when there are text also
[image]

Comment: In search bar, there should be some text, then only it will display the some results.
If the data is dynamic, then it will display a huge results along with scroll. If you click on close button then it will show "we didn't find any matches" and it is by design. If it is a static data , even if we click on close button results will also be displayed.

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT here the same message is displayed when there are text also I have edited the question with the screen shot with the issue

Comment: Could you please check this [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/50.teams-messaging-extensions-search)? ty if that helps

Answer (score 0):

In search bar, there should be some text, then only it will display the some results. If the data is dynamic, then it will display a huge results along with scroll. If you click on close button then it will show "we didn't find any matches" and it is by design. If it is a static data , even if we click on close button results will also be displayed. please check this [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/50.teams-messaging-extensions-search)